# Order of script download and execution with document.write

Tags: javascript, execution, document.write

I have this code :

```
<script>
    document.write('<script src="1.js"><\/script>');
</script>
<script>
    document.write('<script src="2.js"><\/script>');
</script>
<script src="3.js"></script>
```

In the network console I can see that `3.js` is downloaded before `1.js` and  `2.js`. However, the order of execution is as expected (`1.js`, `2.js`, `3.js`).

As far as I know `document.write` is blocking, so the script `3.js` should be downloaded after the calls to `document.write`.

Why did `3.js` download before the scripts inserted with `document.write`?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. I'm not sure what you're referring to by "called". Are you talking about the code being executed or the script being downloaded?

Comment: http://ablogaboutcode.com/2011/06/14/how-javascript-loading-works-domcontentloaded-and-onload/ Take a look at this. Also, note that it actually differs from web browser to web browser.

Comment: In the network console, the inline script '3.js' called before the scripts '1.js'----do you mean the order of downloading the js files?

Answer (score 1):

The order of execution is guaranteed because the [HTML parser blocks whilst parsing and executing JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS). If a script has a `src` URL that hasn't already been downloaded (see below), that has to happen before the script can be parsed. That's bad news - it means that the HTML parser can't carry on reading the document because it is waiting for a potentially slow HTTP response.

In your example the HTML parser has to wait until the first inline `<script>` has been executed before moving onto the next input.

After it has been executed, the next input is the `<script src="1.js"... >` that it inserted into the document. The HTML parser blocks whilst this is fetched, parsed and executed before moving onto the next inline script, and so on. This results in the order of execution:

1. `<script>document.write('<script src="1.js"><\/script>');</script>`
2. `<script src="1.js"></script>`
3. `<script>document.write('<script src="2.js"><\/script>');</script>`
4. `<script src="2.js"></script>`
5. `<script src="3.js"></script>`

However, the browser is free to decide when and how to *download* assets. This can be independent of the order of script execution.

It's common for modern browsers to [pre-fetch assets](http://andydavies.me/blog/2013/10/22/how-the-browser-pre-loader-makes-pages-load-faster/) to reduce the amount of time the HTML parser is blocked whilst scripts download.

You're seeing `3.js` downloaded first because the browser scanned the browser for assets and started downloading scripts immediately. It could only start downloading `1.js` and `2.js` once the HTML parser had parsed and executed their corresponding inline `script` tags.

This means that the HTML parser was blocked whilst downloading `1.js` and `2.js`. If all of your scripts were included directly like `3.js` it is likely that the browser would pre-fetch the three scripts in parallel, making the page load slightly more efficient.

Pre-fetch implementations are browser-specific, so you may see different results in other browsers.